# Testing angular service with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have to test a service with local variables some of methods which do not use local variables pass ok, but some of them fall because the variable is undefined in service scope. Here is my code:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').service('CalculatorService', CalculatorService);

    function CalculatorService() {

        return {
            insertValue : insertValue,
            equals : equals,
            eraseNumber : eraseNumber,
            makeOperation : makeOperation
        }

        var prevValue = 0;
        var operation = '';
        var nextNumber = false;

        function insertValue(digit, display) {
            console.log("prevValue is: " + prevValue);
            if (display === 0 || nextNumber) {
                prevValue = display;
                display = digit;
                nextNumber = false;
            } else {
                display = display + '' + digit;
            }
            return display;
        }

        function equals(display,direct) {
            if (operation === 'plus') {
                display = parseInt(prevValue) + parseInt(display);
            }

            if (operation === 'minus') {
                display = prevValue - display;
            }

            if (operation === 'mult') {
                display = prevValue * display;
            }

            if (operation === 'divide') {
                if (display === 0) {
                    display = 'Divide by 0';
                }else{
                    display = prevValue / display;  
                }

            }
            nextNumber = true;
            prevValue = display;
            if(direct){
                operation='';
            }


            return display;
        }

        function makeOperation(val, display) {
            var firstTime = (operation==='' || operation===undefined);
            var result = equals(display,false)
            operation = val;
            nextNumber = true;
            if(firstTime){
                return display;
            }else{
                return result;
            }

        }

        function eraseNumber(display) {
            display = 0;
            operation = '';
            return display;
        }
    }
})();
```

and this is my test:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    describe('Service: CalculatorService', function() {
        beforeEach(module('app'));

        var mockDisplay = 0;

        it('should change display from 0 to 5', inject(function(CalculatorService) {
            mockDisplay = CalculatorService.insertValue(5,mockDisplay);
            expect(parseInt(mockDisplay)).toEqual(5);

        }));

        it('should change display from 5 to 55', inject(function(CalculatorService) {
            mockDisplay = CalculatorService.insertValue(5,mockDisplay);
            expect(parseInt(mockDisplay)).toEqual(55);
        }));


        it('should not change display (55)', inject(function(CalculatorService) {
            mockDisplay = CalculatorService.makeOperation('divide',mockDisplay);
            expect(parseInt(mockDisplay)).toEqual(55);
        }));

        it('should change display from 55 to 5', inject(function(CalculatorService) {
            mockDisplay = CalculatorService.insertValue(5,mockDisplay);
            expect(parseInt(mockDisplay)).toEqual(5);
        }));




    });
})();
```

How can I test this service?

Comment: If a test fails, it would be nice to know the failure. Why don't you define and initialize mockDisplay in each of your `it` functions, instead of using the same one for all the tests?

Comment: "It is not a bug, it is a feature". It makes sense to use the same mockDisplay. This app is kind of calc. Each time when i insert a digit it must decide to rewrite the previous digit or to concat them. It's all ok till the last test "should change display from 55 to 5" fails, before it I inserted 55 and sign of dividing, after this I am waiting for rewriting 55 with 5, the next test should be equal test and should return 11. But in this failed test the problem is that I expect 5 and get 555, because nextNumber is undefined

Comment: How exactly do they fail and which variables are undefined?

Comment: No, it's a bug. Unit tests should be independant on each other, should be able to run in any order, and should be able to run alone. You should be able to rename any of your it() functions to `fit`, run test test, and have this single test run and pass.

Comment: @estus these variables fail:
        var prevValue = 0;
        var operation = '';
        var nextNumber = false;

"the problem is that I expect 5 and get 555"

Comment: @JBNizet I agree you, but I think if I concat all these tests in one the problem will remain

Comment: @JBNizet you are right! I verified this way and it works. Can you provide your comment as an answer? I want to select it as the best. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
    var prevValue = 0;
    var operation = '';
    var nextNumber = false;

    return {
        insertValue : insertValue,
        equals : equals,
        eraseNumber : eraseNumber,
        makeOperation : makeOperation
    }
```

Local variables are hoisted, and early return causes them to be `undefined`.

The dependency on local variables ceases to be a problem when they are exposed as private properties that reflect the internal state of the service and can be mocked or verified.

```
var obj = {
    _prevValue: 0,
    _operation: '',
    _nextNumber: false,
    ...
};

return obj;
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I modified it and now it is not undefined. Thanks. But The answer for my trouble is that all these tests should be included in one.

Comment: @Filosssof In fact, they shouldn't. Unit testing supposes that the units can be efficiently tested in isolation. A good test-wise design is to expose local variables as private service properties, so the entire service state could be mocked in each spec.

Comment: I agree you, I don't know how can I test in isolation the divide button, before it I should insert some digits, and after this I'll call equal method. And this test will be kind of integration test.

Comment: When unit tests are written the right way, per service integration test can be skipped, integration test can be extended to several components work together (service + controller). It always depends on particular case.

Comment: I see no problem with divide. Internal properties are mocked in the beginning of the spec with what they would look like after previous operation. Then divide operation is performed and internal properties are checked with `expect`, this guarantees 100% coverage and durability of the specs.